# Do we want a tag for the Transformers live action movies?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen questions questions about all *Transformers* live action movies.

- [Do Transformers ever transform with people on board?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/184877/19561)
- [Which radio/TV broadcasts were sampled by Bumblebee in the Transformers movie?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15225/19561)

The first one is tagged with [transformers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformers), the second one with that plus all separate film tags.

**Should we create a tag to cover all *Transformers* live action movies to tag questions such as these with?**

If so, what should it be?

Comment: We don't have a tag for all the Harry potter films, or all the harry potter books, nor do we have one for all the Marvel TV shows on netflix. These films are part of the wider canon of the transformers, all of which are (afaia) linked, so no, we don't need one. Although the newer transformer films should have 'transformers' prepended to their tags.

Comment: Except the Movie universe *is* a separate continuity of a larger franchise, and we have continuity tags like marvel-cinematic-universe, dceu, and arrowverse. The Bayformer/Live-action movies are *not* linked to other continuities excluding tie-in comics. As of now, there are [six major continuities](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Continuities).

Comment: is there an official name for the live-action movies, a la MCU? Or at least a widely recognized fan one a la Arrowverse? I know it's called the bayformers universe a lot but that my impression is that's intended to be a derogatory term.

Comment: @Edlothiad the marvel TV shows on Netflix are all tagged `[marvel-cinematic-universe]` to distinguish them from other material, particularly comic books and movies with the same names.

Comment: Officially, "live-action" is the only thing I've seen/heard it referred to as. `[transformers-live-action]` should work

Comment: Remember folks: You're voting for the tags, not the films themselves ;)

Comment: @KutuluMike all I could tell from the wikipedia page is that they're included in the whole transformers canon as one huge mashup. Like the various universes in the Marvel comics, but I wouldn't know much past a quick wiki search

Comment: I wish somebody had asked if we wanted live action Transformers movies

Comment: @KutuluMike “is there an official name for the live-action movies, a la MCU?” — not one that meets the site’s “Be nice” policy.

Comment: @edlothiad - These films have plots?

Comment: @Valorum well the Kabooms and the pew pees come in a specific order which seems to have some sort of organised structure, but beyond that, HA!

Comment: @Edlothiad - Each one seems to just be a direct sequel of the next, generally set a few months or years later.  Is there a shared universe beyond them simply being a single film *continuity*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the live-action film series (commonly know among the Transformers community as... the [live-action film series](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Live-action_film_series)) should at the very *least* have its own tag.

It's typical for us to do so. See [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) or [nolan-batman-trilogy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nolan-batman-trilogy).

We've also applied tags for individual movies, in the case of [star-trek-2009](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2009), [star-trek-into-darkness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-into-darkness), and [star-trek-beyond](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-beyond), even though they all also belong under the franchise tag of [star-trek-reboot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-reboot) (although it's not applied correctly to all matching questions, that's a different issue).

In this case, I don't currently see a need for individual film tags.

**I would recommend [transformers-live-action](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformers-live-action) or [transformers-live-action-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformers-live-action-series) with a wiki excerpt that specifies it's about the live action films as well as the related tie-in media.**

The number of questions is relatively small, so that shouldn't be seen as a hurdle in fixing this (which is the case for [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter), which is, as usual, grandfathered in as an exception to normal tagging practices).

---

I've accepted this answer and have started adding [transformers-live-action-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformers-live-action-series) to relevant questions.

Comment: [tag:transformers-live-action-universe]? [tag:transformers-bayniverse]?

Comment: @SQB "Bayformers" and "Bayverse" are often used as ways to talk _down_ about the series, so not sure it belongs her. -universe would be within the tag limits, too, but most references to it online call it the "film series" _not_ universe

Comment: Almost need a [michael-bay] tag. [michael-bay-transformers]